# Videos only playing on Chrome & Safari but not FF (RoR)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, video, ruby-on-rails-4, jwplayer

So, I'm using the [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com) to stream/play videos on my web application. Now the issue is, the video player only displays on Chrome & Safari, but not on FireFox.

Below is the code for the video player in my app:

```
<div class="left">
      <div class="video-img">
        <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/Nu3Cav_oEeKU_RIxOUCPzg.js"></script>
        <div id='my-video<%= @clip.video.id %>'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jwplayer('my-video<%= @clip.video.id %>').setup({
                playlist: [{
                        image: "<%= @clip.video.thumbnail_url %>",
                        sources: [
                            { file: "<%= video_url(@clip.video.remote_id, :smil) %>" },
                            { file: "<%= video_url(@clip.video.remote_id, :m3u8) %>" }
                        ]
                    }],
                primary: "html",
                width: '100%',
                rtmp: {
                        bufferlength: 7
                    }
            });
        </script>
        <%#= image_tag('video-img.jpg') %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help on getting this video player to display and work on FireFox would be great, thanks!

Comment: Please give us a link to your site. The loading of the script from jwpsrv.com should be in the head section of the page, rather than in the body, but that's probably not the source of your problem.

Comment: Could be an issue with the encoding.  Are you using the fallback for flash and is that setup correctly?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Hey Ethan, we're speaking via email but here's the link anyways: http://rocky-depths-3714.herokuapp.com/clips/blabla

Comment: I replied to your email about this as well as the other stackoverflow thread.

Comment: Thanks, I've found some documentation on how to configure S3's content_type. Working on it, I'll let you know how it goes. Cheers!